# how to change rails 3 database from sqlite3 to mysql5 in the middle of development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rail 3. Can I directly go changing the database.yml and... what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `database.yml` to look something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: <database name>
  pool: 5
  username: <user name>
  password: <password>
  host: <host>
```

Then, just run `rake db:schema:load` to have it create your tables.  Then test!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly yes, but it can be that there are some small differences between sqlite and mysql. So test well when you change.

Comment: thanks. After the change and adjustment, I should do "rake db:reset
rake db:migrate", right?

Comment: I think rake db:migrate is enough. Rails creates a special table in the database for keeping the migration and that one should not be there in mysql.

Comment: `rake db:migrate` will run through all the migrations files again. This is less reliable than `rake db:schema:load` for recreating the current database schema.  However, it is necessary to run `rake db:migrate` if you have code in the migrations that modify data or other things that don't affect schema.